# Datatable is not binding after uploading in production server but working perfectly in local

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, iis-7

Datatable  is not binding after uploading in production server but working perfectly in local and live Server is:IIS  7.0

Below is c# code.

```
protected void FillGrid(string Paravalue)
{
    try
    {
        bo.Para1 =Request.QueryString["ApplicationStatus"].ToString();pplicationStatus
        bo.Para2 = Session["Userid"].ToString();// SubmittedBy
        bo.Para3 = Paravalue;//Paravalue
        DataTable dt = bl.Get_Applications(bo);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            lbl_texxt.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PositionTitle"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {

            lbl_texxt.Text = "No Data";
        }
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            btnExport.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnExport.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("er" + ex);
    }
}
```

below is Gridview code.

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PositionId"
              AllowSorting="True" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid"
              GridLines="None" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
              HeaderStyle-Height="25px" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
              Width="900px" PageSize="50">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="30px" />
      <ItemStyle CssClass="th" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="30px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PositionTitle" HeaderText="Position Title">
      <ItemStyle CssClass="th" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="250px" />
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="250px" Height="25px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Openfor" HeaderText="Open for">
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="140px" />
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="140px" Height="25px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Positions" HeaderText="Total Position(s)">
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="140px" />
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="140px" Height="25px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_state" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("State") %>'></asp:Label>
        -
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_City" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      <ItemStyle Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="pr_list_count2_action" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Count") %>' onClick="ViewApplications">0</asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle Width="140px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      <ItemStyle Width="140px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="true" CssClass="grid_row1_action" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PositionId" Visible="false">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_ProjectID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PositionId") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
  <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
  <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <center>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_nodata" runat="server" Text="No applications pending for review." OnClick="lnkbtn_nodata_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    </center>
  </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

I restored live db into local and check working fine showing 32000 thousand data into gridview in local host. One more thing Its taking time to load in live server after showing `No Data`. As also kept try catch block and getting 'No Data' and ApplicationStatus query string value change then that data is showing that is below 10000 thousand records.

Comment: any help from stack over flow users?.

Comment: there problem with your database. you have to also host your database to iis.

Comment: why problem with database? already other think is working with database in live site. because of 32000 thousand load and one more thing application server and database server is different not on the same server that's the reason. @Asif.Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current GrivView-Paging wil be tunned by object datasource  and load the records based on Pageindex (on-demand) and removed paging from Gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your problem there is no mistake in your coding. But it may be possible your connection string wrongly defined in the class which you are using for filling the datatable. So Please write everything on same page don't use class for some times for finding the errors. You can use below code. It may help you for finding the error.

```
protected void FillGrid(string Paravalue)
{
    try
    {
        bo.Para1 = Request.QueryString["ApplicationStatus"].ToString();//ApplicationStatus
        bo.Para2 = Session["Userid"].ToString();// SubmittedBy
        bo.Para3 = Paravalue;//Paravalue
        //DataTable dt = bl.Get_Applications(bo);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["your connection name"].ConnectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your query or procedure name", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Para1", bo.Para1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Para1", bo.Para1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Para1", bo.Para1);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            lbl_texxt.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PositionTitle"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {

            lbl_texxt.Text = "No Data";
        }
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            btnExport.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnExport.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("er" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: May be your thinking is wrong because other base on query string I am filling data into gridview and other query string value filling data in gridview on same page and its not connection string issue. @Nripendra Ojha

Comment: ok.. I am not saying you are wrong. You can take it as a request. please also try this and inform me it is working on server or not?

Comment: Can you tell me the reason to call directly from page?. @Nripendra Ojha